# Why does just one (of 8) numeric predictor variables return NA when I run lm()?

Tags: r, linear-regression

I'm trying to build a linear regression model using eight independent variables, but when I run `lm()` one variable--*what I anticipate being my best predictor!*--keeps returning NA. I'm still new to R, and I cannot find a solution.

Here are my independent variables:

> - TEMPERATURE
> - HUMIDITY
> - WIND_SPEED
> - VISIBILITY
> - DEW_POINT_TEMPERATURE
> - SOLAR_RADIATION
> - RAINFALL
> - SNOWFALL

My df is `training_set` and looks like:
[image]

I'm not sure whether this matters, but `training_set` is 75% of my original df, and `testing_set` is 25%. Created thusly:

```
set.seed(1234)
split_bike_sharing <- sample(c(rep(0, round(0.75 * nrow(bike_sharing_df))), rep(1, round(0.25 * nrow(bike_sharing_df)))))
```

This gave me `table(split_bike_sharing)`:

| 0 | 1 |
| --- | --- |
| 6349 | 2116 |

And then I did:

```
training_set <- bike_sharing_df[split_bike_sharing == 0, ]
testing_set <- bike_sharing_df[split_bike_sharing == 1, ]
```

The structure of `training_set` is like:
[image]

To create the model I run the code:

```
lm_model_weather=lm(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT ~ TEMPERATURE + HUMIDITY + WIND_SPEED + VISIBILITY + DEW_POINT_TEMPERATURE +
```

SOLAR_RADIATION + RAINFALL + SNOWFALL, data = training_set)

However, as you can see the resultant model returns `RAINFALL` as NA. Here is the resultant model:

[image]

My first thought was to check `RAINFALL` datatype, which is *numeric* with range 0-1 (because at an earlier step I performed min-max normalization). But `SNOWFALL` also is *numeric*, and I've done nothing (that I know of!) to the one but not the other. My second thought was to confirm that `RAINFALL` contains enough values to work, and that does not appear to be an issue: `summary(training_set$RAINFALL)`:

[image]

So, how do I correct the NAs in `RAINFALL`? Truly I will be most grateful for your guidance to a solution.

**UPDATE 10 MARCH 2022**
I've now checked for collinearity:

```
X <- model.matrix(RENTED_BIKE_COUNT ~ ., data = training_set)
X2 <- caret::findLinearCombos(X)
print(X2)
```

This gave me:
[image]

I believe this means certain columns are jointly multicollinear. As you can see, columns 8, 13, and 38 are:

- [8] is `RAINFALL`
- [13] is `SEASONS_WINTER`
- [38] is `HOUR_23`

**Question**: if I want to preserve `RAINFALL` as a predictor variable (viz., return proper values rather than NAs when I run lm()), what do I do? Remove columns [13] and [38] from the dataset?

Comment: Your model summary tells you "`1 not defined because of singularities`". `RAINFALL` must be a linear combination of some of your other predictors, resulting in a singular matrix.

Comment: Thank you for your response, Gregor. But I don't understand how `RAINFALL` could have become such a combination. It's a standalone column; at no point did I have to generate that column out of other columns' data. Forgive me if I'm asking a dumb question.

Comment: You're question isn't dumb. Check the correlation matrix of your data `cor(training_set)` to see if it's perfectly correlated with any one variable. There's an excellent answer on the subject [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/70910/7515).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71270248/error-warning-on-running-glm-in-r-coefficients-1-not-defined-because-of-sing/71270467#71270467

Comment: @GregorThomas, `cor(training_set)` gives me an error: "Error in cor(training_set) : 'x' must be numeric". Would it still be productive to run cor() *only* on the numeric columns? Thanks for directing me to the explanation at that link (which I definitely needed to read twice!).

Comment: Thank you, @BenBolker, for directing me to the other question and your reply there. If the suspicion is that my `RAINFALL` is either completely or nearly collinear with another predictor variable, should I just try removing the other predictors in the lm() one at a time until `RAINFALL` *doesn't* return as NAs? Or perhaps I've misunderstood your linked answer. Thank you again.

Comment: Could you provide small part of your data so that other users can reproduce your error message? I can't open your images. It's weird that my internet provider is now blocking the website used to store your images.

Comment: The code in the linked answer gives an explicit recipe for finding out which combinations of variables in your model are multicollinear ...

Comment: @BenBolker, I've updated my original question in light of reviewing the code in your linked answer. I appreciate your help on this. Two months ago I had never even heard of 'R'!